# Pip3 can't be "loaded" as a library/package, no matter what I try, after upgrading to Ubunta 18

Tags: apt, lubuntu, python, pip, paths

The question was on Stack Overflow, but it is too Unix/Ubuntu-sepcific.

My problem (see below where I have earlier posts) is that I can't get pip (or, more accurately, pip3) to load or work.  APT get pip3-python (or whatever the online help tells you to do) can never locate the package.  I am using virtauenv's, and after a lot of work I discovered where my lib/..../site-packages/(distros)/pip.py lives under a 'distro' folder site URL called either python2.7 or python3.5.  By following it to the end, I was able to see this while the venv was active.

"old" Pip works OK (I think) after using apt install to bootstrap pip for 2.7.

But for python3 I never get success. Since I have no pip, I can't use pip to upgrade. Instead, I tried APT, but APT can't find (or can't load) the pip3 version for pip.  I even used curl to load a copy of pip3 from a source and 'force it in' to the /..../site-packages/python3.5 folder using curl, but there is no CLI command that can access it (it in fact fails because it can't load executables or modules it needs.  For example, after a lot of work I get this error message after saying 'pip3':

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/lee/Unix/quantilla-harden/q7root/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
   from pip._internal.cli.main import main
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

As I say, my own sleuthing around found that an older version of pip is in my personal path ...~/.../site-packages/python2.7/pip (along with other packages)

Bu there is no parallel file in .../site-packages/python3.6.

If it is of value, this is how I got the virtual environment to work:

1. created a directory with makedir called fixpipenv
2. moved to that directory
3. did "virtualenv ." (this seems to have introduced a "fixpipenv" below the one created with
4. ```
      this command, i.e., there are stacked "fixpipenv"ls directories.)
   ```
5. ```
   checked; there is now a '/bin' in the (lower) fixpipenv directory
   ```
6. ```
   typed . bin/activate My CLI prompt has now switched to the "fixpipenv" 
       notification we are in a virtual environment
   ```

Now pip comes to life, but at version like so which works for "old" Python:

(fixpipenv) me@me-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~/fixpipenv/fixpipenv$ pip list
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January

1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer
maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January
2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Package Version

When I try pip3, it looks like so:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/lee/Unix/quantilla-harden/q7root/bin/pip3", line 7, in

from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/lee/Unix/quantilla-harden/q7root/bin/pip3", line 7, in

from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

My own sluicing found that an older version of pip is in my personal path ...~/.../site-packages/python2.7/pip (along with other packages)

There is no parallel file in .../site-packages/python3.6.

Again, I apologize for the repeated updating, but no one so far has found the solution so I keep editing it down to find the likeliest problem after each step of looking at it and trying to fix the problem. The question at top (here) let's anyone focus on the realities; the bottom shows all the history to date:

---

Prior Question: How does Unix find the executable for every command? I presume from some poking around I did that it simply goes through the $PATH in sequence, looking for an executable with the same name. In other words, if you type 'grep', it transits the tree form $PATH looking for an executable file named "grep.py" (were grep written in Python), and if that fails reports it as such. But, is there another approach? For example, is is each command tied to a 'export' in a hidden file that maps each of the executables to an executable-tagged file that creates an alias, along the lines of grep=/.../bin/grep.py I am having a terrible time getting pip to work on a computer I upgraded to Ubuntu 18, and am trying to figure out why my system can't find pip anymore, even if I copy the files into what looks like a logical path on Unix that holds a lot of the CLI executables.
In the alternate, couldn't I just save the actual file for pip in a directory on my $PATH, or add a new place for such things and change my $PATH (under a virtualenv environment) to make it work?**

Comment: Ubuntu 18?  So this is a *snap* based Ubuntu Core 18 installation? and not a server or desktop release. Starting with your actual release may help, as there is no Ubuntu 18 (the *snap* based Ubuntu Core 18 is closest, as *yy* format is used only for *snap* based releases; all *deb* based releases use *yy.mm* format as they have multiple releases per year).  Please clarify your release, and what do you get for `python -V; python3 -V; pip -V; pip3 -V`  How does Lubuntu relate? as that is a desktop usually not used on *snap* based IoT/appliance releases.